# Golang: panic after mutex locks have been held for too long

Tags: go, locking

I am trying to figure out what is that is making my program hanging, most of my locks shouldn't be held for more than 200 ms. (actually much less!)

I want to create two new functions (`Lock()` and `Unlock()`) so that Lock will have a timer that will panic if Lock has been held for more than 200 ms.

This is my current attempt, but it doesn't work, any hint?

```
type ShardKV struct {
  lockChan chan bool
}

func (kv *App) lock(reason string) {
    kv.mu.Lock()

    f := func () {
        fmt.Println("PANIC: ms passed")
        select {
        case <- kv.lockChan:
            //
        default:
            panic("PANIC: " + reason)
        }
  }
    time.AfterFunc(time.Second * 10, f)
}

func (kv *App) unlock(reason string) {
    kv.lockChan <- true
    kv.mu.Unlock()
}
```

Comment: How do you create the channel? It has to be buffered for this code to work

Comment: Your code waits for 10 seconds, but you say you intend for 200 ms. You did not state why your code does not work, could this be the reason ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the return value of `time.AfterFunc`. Here is a working example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Foo struct {
    m sync.Mutex
    timer *time.Timer
}

func (f *Foo) lock() {
    f.m.Lock()
    f.timer = time.AfterFunc(3 * time.Second, func() {
        panic("Too long!")
    })
}

func (f *Foo) unlock() {
    f.timer.Stop()
    f.m.Unlock()
}

func main() {
    foo := &Foo{
        sync.Mutex{},
        &time.Timer{},
    }

    foo.lock()

    // Uncomment this to see the difference
    //time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

    foo.unlock()
    fmt.Println("Success!")
}
```

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/WVPp0_Iqlb

Answer (score 0):

Your lock function waits for 10 seconds befor calling the f function which holds the select statement, a simpler way of achieving what you are trying to do might be this:

```
func (kv *App) lock(reason string) {
    kv.mu.Lock()
    select {
    case <- kv.lockChan:
        //
    case <-time.After(time.Second * 10):
        panic("PANIC: " + reason)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a better approach than what the OP's code attempts. It's easier to understand *and* performs better both.

Comment: Your code is wrong. The OP's lock function locks the mutex, starts the timer and returns. The timer will wait in the background and after 10 seconds will check whether the mutex is unlocked. Your lock function will block for 10 seconds or until the mutex is unlocked. That's not what the OP wants and your solution is worse regardles. You don't block for 10 seconds, you wait in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You have said you want your code to panic if the lock has been hold for 200 ms, but you gave the timer 10 seconds to wait. This will simply wait for 10 seconds before panicing instead of 200. I have tried your code editing it the following way :

```
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)


type App struct {
    mu sync.Mutex
    lockChan chan bool
}

func (kv *App) lock(reason string) {
    kv.mu.Lock()

    f := func () {
        fmt.Println("PANIC: ms passed")
        select {
        case <- kv.lockChan:
        //
        default:
            panic("PANIC: " + reason)
        }
    }
    time.AfterFunc(time.Millisecond * 200, f)
}

func (kv *App) unlock(reason string) {
    kv.lockChan <- true
    kv.mu.Unlock()
}

func NewApp() *App {
    app := App{}
    app.lockChan = make(chan bool)
    return &app
}

func main() {
    app := NewApp()
    app.lock("locking")
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 300)

}
```

Above code works just fine and panics. If you drop the duration in the main function to `200 * time.Millisecond`, it will not panic and just stop running.